Output multiline value from github composite action so a subscribing workflow can use it
In my GitHub composite action, I'm trying to output a multi-line string from a file so that the workflow that subscribes to my action can put that text in an issue. I couldn't set the output to a multi-line value the normal way:
  FOLDER=$(ls -d */ | grep -E '^my-dynamically-named-artifact-folder-*')
  FILE_PATH="${FOLDER}file.txt"
  echo "FILE_PATH=$FILE_PATH" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  echo "$FILE_PATH"
  # Get contents of files if they exist
  if [ -f "$FILE_PATH" ]; then
    FILE_TEXT=$(cat "$FILE_PATH")
  else
    FILE_TEXT="report.txt does not exist"
  fi
  
  echo "This is the file text:\n$FILE_TEXT"
  
  echo "FILE_TEXT=$FILE_TEXT" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
  echo "FILE_TEXT=$FILE_TEXT" >> $GITHUB_ENV

The console logged the right output for the file text with the echo you can see above, but I got these errors in my action afterwards:
Error: Unable to process file command 'env' successfully.
Error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'name')
Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully.
Error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'name')

The subscribing workflow got an empty string. I did some research and then created the variable with the below:
  echo 'FILE_TEXT<<EOF' >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  echo $FILE_TEXT >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  echo 'EOF' >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

It completed without an error, but it converted the output to one line of text, which isn't what I want. After more research, I tried converting to base 64 before putting it into a variable:
  B64=$(echo -n "$DEBUG_LOG" | base64)
  echo "B64=$B64" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

It converted part of the text to base 64 and then stopped in the middle, maybe around some dashes (-). Right after that, it got another error:
Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully.
Error: Invalid format 'aVeryShortNumberOfBase64EncodingCharacters'

The subscribing workflow I wrote did then put that partially encoded text into the issue correctly, but that's obviously not good enough.
I didn't try replacing the new line characters because I found responses that said it stopped working when github changed how we create the output variables.
How do I get this multi-line text to my users so they can put it in their issues?

This is kind of a sideways solution, but it was good enough for what I needed. I couldn't find any solution to get the multi-line string out. Instead, I put the name of the file in the output. That way, the subscribing workflow didn't have to worry about any changes I make to the directory structure of the artifacts I create. They also don't have to worry about the fact that my action generates the folder name dynamically. They can then use the contents of the file themselves.
The simplified (untested) composite action code:
name: "Get file"
outputs:
  FILEPATH:
    description: 'An empty string ("") or the path to the artifact file. Remember to check for the existence of the file before using it.'
    value: ${{ steps.files.outputs.INFO_FILE_PATH }}
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    # other steps
    - name: "Make paths"
      if: ${{ always() }}
      id: files
      shell: bash
      run: |
        # Example value: "files123/"
        FOLDER=$(ls -d */ | grep -E '^files*' || true)
        echo "$FOLDER"
        if [[ "$FOLDER" = "" ]]; then
          echo "No artifacts"
        else
          PATH_TO_MULTILINE_TEXT="${FOLDER}info.txt"
          if [ -f "$PATH_TO_MULTILINE_TEXT" ]; then
            echo "Found info file"
          else
            echo "Missing info file"
            PATH_TO_MULTILINE_TEXT=""
          fi
        fi
        echo "INFO_FILE_PATH=$PATH_TO_MULTILINE_TEXT" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

The subscribing workflow then uses it like this (also untested):
name: Do stuff
on:
  push:
jobs:
  a job name:
    # other stuff
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Run the composite action
        id: the_action
        uses: owner/repo@branch
      - name: Make issue with the multi-line info
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
          INFO_PATH: "${{ steps.the_action.outputs.FILEPATH }}"
        run: |
          if [ -f "${{ env.INFO_PATH }}" ]; then
            INFO_TEXT=$(cat "${{ env.INFO_PATH }}")
          else
            INFO_TEXT="Missing info path"
          fi

          gh issue create --repo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY" --title "Some title" --body "See the action ${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}. See the info output below.

          $INFO_TEXT"

Not sure if this can really be the accepted answer, though, since it doesn't solve the actual problem.
